# Why Circle detection detects many circles than its there?

Tags: opencv

I am using following functions to detect images. However, it detects thousands of circles instead of 16. How can I make sure it only detects what I see? Changing Radius or Relative intensity do not make any difference.
The images I used is this :[image]

```
Bitmap ImageBitmap = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;

            var filter = new FiltersSequence(new IFilter[]
            {
                      Grayscale.CommonAlgorithms.BT709,
                      new Threshold(0x40)
            });
            var binaryImage = filter.Apply(ImageBitmap);

       //     for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {

          //      System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imagePath);
                //      GrayBMP_File.CreateGrayBitmapFile(image, "c:/path/to/8bpp/image.bmp");




                //    Bitmap ImageBitmap = Convert.Gra ImageBitmap.Con

                HoughCircleTransformation circleTransform = new HoughCircleTransformation(50);
                // apply Hough circle transform
                circleTransform.ProcessImage(binaryImage);
                Bitmap houghCirlceImage = circleTransform.ToBitmap();
                // get circles using relative intensity
                HoughCircle[] circles = circleTransform.GetCirclesByRelativeIntensity(0.9);
                int numCircles = circleTransform.CirclesCount;
                label1.Text = numCircles.ToString();
                pictureBox1.Image = houghCirlceImage;
                System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(ImageBitmap);
                foreach (HoughCircle circle in circles)
                {
                    g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Green, circle.X, circle.Y, 10,10);
                }
                pictureBox1.Image = ImageBitmap;
//                ImageBitmap.Dispose();
//                binaryImage.Dispose();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `python` solution from [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg',0)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                            param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
d=1
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

    crop_img=img[i[0]-i[2]-2:i[0]+i[2]+2,i[1]-i[2]-2:i[1]+i[2]+2]
    cv2.imshow('cropped circle',crop_img)
    cv2.imwrite('test_%d.png'%d,crop_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    d+=1

cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
print(len(circles[0,:]))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**16**

Comment: This is fantastic but in my application, I need it in C# GUI. In the worst case scenario I could call this in background.

Comment: Hope anyone else can help you to do this in C# since I'm not from that background. :)

Comment: Hi Ishara, Could you modify this script to split the circles (square image slightly larger than circle) and save into original image location with original_name_bump_number format ?

Comment: @PCG I edited the solution as per your requirement as I understand.

Comment: Thank you Ishara. I will try this out. Also I was able to get the C# working with using C# wrapper EmguCV. Now I need to check which one is faster.